# Class tufte-book and R listings code box width problem

Tags: listings, r, tufte, knitr, sweave

When I run the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{Sweavel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%%%%%%%
% R example
%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{rex}{}{}{}{.45\textwidth}{}{}{1 mm}{}
\theoremstyle{rex}
\newtheorem{rexample}{R example}[chapter]

%%%%%%%%%%
% boxes
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{style2}{
    backgroundcolor=gray!10,
}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% crossref
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \crefname{rexample}{Example}{Examples}%
%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% layout
%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}
%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%
% listings
%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\indexfunction}[1]{\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language = R,
  frame = single,
}
\def\Rcolor{\color{black}}
\def\Routcolor{\color{black}}
\def\Rcommentcolor{\color{red}}
\def\Rbackground{\color[rgb]{0.992, 0.965, 0.894}}
\def\Routbackground{\color[rgb]{0.894, 0.965, 0.992}}
\definecolor{lightYellow}{rgb}{0.992, 0.965, 0.894}
\sethlcolor{lightYellow}
%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% book metadata
%%%%%%%%%%
\title[]{}
\author[]{}
\publisher{}
%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{rexample}\label{set1}\hfill{}\begin{Sinput}
setS <- letters[1:5] %>% print()
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
\end{Soutput}
\end{rexample}\end{Schunk}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{rexample}\label{set2}\hfill{}\begin{Sinput}
"e" %in% setS
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] TRUE
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
"f" %in% setS
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] FALSE
\end{Soutput}
\end{rexample}\end{Schunk}

\end{document}
```

which contains R input and output code, the following output is produced

[image: LaTeX output compiled using knitr]

Notice that the width of the input box is different from the width of the output box. How do I make those equal in width?

This code requires `Sweavel.sty` available here [`sweavel.sty` is generated when one runs knir on an .Rnw file which contains LaTeX and R code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/buw5n6oxsn65fgu/Sweavel.sty?dl=0)

Comment: The original file from which this .tex was generated (as an intermediate step before generating the pdf output) was of type .Rnw, which contains both LaTeX and R code. I have edited the original query to include a link to Sweavel.sty as it was generated when I compiled my .Rnw file with knitr, a program that "knits" the LaTeX with the R code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to redefine the definition of the style `Routstyle` for listings.

In your used file `Sweavel.sty` it is defined as

```
\lstdefinestyle{Routstyle}{%
  fancyvrb=false,
  literate={~}{{$\sim$}}1{R^2}{{$R^{2}$}}2{^}{{$^{\scriptstyle\wedge}$}}1{R-squared}{{$R^{2}$}}2,%
  frame=single, 
  framerule=0.2pt,
  framesep=1pt,
  basicstyle=\Routcolor\Routsize\ttfamily,%
  backgroundcolor=\Routbackground}
```

You can use the following code in your preamble instead:

```
\lstdefinestyle{Routstyle}{%
  language=R,%
  basicstyle={\Routcolor\Sweavesize\ttfamily},
  backgroundcolor=\Routbackground,%
}
```

So with the following complete code

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{Sweavel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{soul}

%%%%%%%%%%
% R example
%%%%%%%%%%
\newtheoremstyle{rex}{}{}{}{.45\textwidth}{}{}{1 mm}{}
\theoremstyle{rex}
\newtheorem{rexample}{R example}[chapter]

%%%%%%%%%%
% boxes
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{style2}{
    backgroundcolor=gray!10,
}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% crossref
%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
    \crefname{rexample}{Example}{Examples}%
%%%%%%%%%%

%%%%%%%%%%
% layout
%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\blankpage}{\newpage\hbox{}\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage}
%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%
% listings
%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\indexfunction}[1]{\index{#1@\texttt{#1}}}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language = R,
  frame = single,
}
\def\Rcolor{\color{black}}
\def\Routcolor{\color{black}}
\def\Rcommentcolor{\color{red}}
\def\Rbackground{\color[rgb]{0.992, 0.965, 0.894}}
\def\Routbackground{\color[rgb]{0.894, 0.965, 0.992}}
\definecolor{lightYellow}{rgb}{0.992, 0.965, 0.894}
\sethlcolor{lightYellow}
%%%%%%%%%%

\lstdefinestyle{Routstyle}{% <==========================================
  language=R,%
  basicstyle={\Routcolor\Sweavesize\ttfamily},
  backgroundcolor=\Routbackground,%
} % <===================================================================
%%%%%%%%%%
% book metadata
%%%%%%%%%%
\title[]{}
\author[]{}
\publisher{}
%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{rexample}
\label{set1}\hfill{}
\begin{Sinput}
setS <- letters[1:5] %>% print()
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
\end{Soutput}
\end{rexample}
\end{Schunk}

\begin{Schunk}
\begin{rexample}
\label{set2}\hfill{}
\begin{Sinput}
"e" %in% setS
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] TRUE
\end{Soutput}
\begin{Sinput}
"f" %in% setS
\end{Sinput}
\begin{Soutput}
[1] FALSE
\end{Soutput}
\end{rexample}
\end{Schunk}

\end{document}
```

with the following result:

[image: resulting pdf]